# jQuery Ajax fails on Android tablet browser

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am developing on a [Samsung tablet](http://www.samsung.com/global/microsite/galaxytab/10.1/index.html) which has default browser.

The ISS tells me this info : Mozilla/5.0+(Linux;+U;+Android+3.2;+en-us;+GT-P7500+Build/HTJ85B)

The ajax call keeps failing with Error 0 and no information when posting info to server. On every other browser it works without problems.

Any idea why ?

here is the code i use : 
status is 0
end textStatus is undefined

```
$.ajax({
            url: uri,
            contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "text",
            data: input,
            type: 'POST',
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                doShowError("Error:" + jqXHR.status + "--" + textStatus + "--" + errorThrown + "-"+ jqXHR.readyState); 
            }
            }
```

Edit 1 : `Mozilla/5.0+(Linux;+U;+Android+3.2;+en-us;+GT-P7500+Build/HTJ85B)+AppleWebKit/534.13+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Version/4.0+Safari/534.13` this is all I get.

Comment: I've seen at least 2 other threads with "Mozilla for Android" problems. I wonder if their JavaScript implementation simply isn't complete yet.

Comment: Yeah, but so far the solutions I found and tried from their bug tracker weren't helpful. They closed both bugs due to inactivity.

Comment: @Floradu88: **Every** web browser says "Mozilla" in the user agent string. This particular browser is quite definitely based on WebKit and has nothing to do with Mozilla.

Comment: @GregPettit: Firefox uses exactly the same engine on Android as on the desktop. But this question is quite certainly **not** about Firefox.

Comment: @WladimirPalant I'm willing to buy that it's not the new Firefox for Android (unless Floradu88 says it is), but it's a stretch to say that EVERY web browser says "Mozilla" in the UA string. Simply not true.

Comment: Would it help if i found out what webkit it is used?

Comment: The browser hasn't any description or version.

Comment: @GregPettit: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_agent#Format

Comment: @Floradu88: The full user agent string now shows that it is WebKit 534.13 - the usual version on Android 3.2. And the browser itself doesn't have any name (it's the default browser).

Comment: @WladimirPalant Exactly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found a solution :

It seems that when doing things asynchronously in this Webkit browser, when receiving multiple chunks of data from a large response, the browser responds with status 0 which means error, instead of 206 which means partial result. The advice for my case is that we should used sync in order to fix the issue until this bug is fixed : http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=14924 or this one http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/8343