# jQuery post error on Android 2.3.x (working on Android v4.x)

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, cordova

I'm writing my first Android app with PhoneGap 2.5; the app is straight simple, just read local gps coordinates and send them to a remote server along with some device data (uuid, android version) and some input fields.
when the app start it sends a sort of "device registration" to remote server and receives back some data

As of now i'm only using jquery v1.9.1, no jquery mobile nor other javascript libraries.

Here's the code

```
onDeviceReady: function() {
    $.support.cors = true;
    app.deviceRegister();
    // navigator.splashscreen.hide();
},

deviceRegister: function() {
    var params = {
        'device_uuid': window.device.uuid,
        'device_platform': window.device.platform,
        'device_model': window.device.model,
        'device_version': window.device.version,
    };
    var url = app.data.url + 'devices/register'; // app.data.url defined elsewhere
    $.ajax(url, {
        type: "POST",
        data: params,
        timeout: 5000,
        success: function(response) {
            // updates html with received data
            $("#user_badge").html(response.badge);
            $("#user_name").html(response.full_name);
        },
        error: function(x, t, m) {
            if (t === 'timeout') {
                navigator.notification.alert('timeout error');
            } else {
                navigator.notification.alert('error: ' + t);
            }
        },
        dataType: 'json'
    });
},
```

When applied to Android v4.x (both emulator and real device) it works perfectly, data is sent to remote server and response is correctly managed.

The problem is if i run the app on Android v2.3.x (both emulator and real devices): no data is sent and all i get is an alert with "error: error".

I assume there's something worng between android 2.3 and jquery 1.9, but i just can't get where the problem is.

Any guess?

Comment: Try to check the solution on this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11434930/jquery-ajax-fails-on-android-tablet-browser

Comment: i tried to add a "async: false" to $.ajax options, but that didn't work.
i also tried older jquery version (1.6.4, 1.7.2, 1.8.3) without success.
any other guess?

Comment: did you change the access origin parameter in config.xml?

Answer (score 0):

your params object has an extra , at the end.

Answer (score 0):

I'm betting `app.data.url` is a secure URL (https). I had the same issue and had to write an exception for Android versions below 4 to use a normal, non-secured, http connection. Never found an answer on why it wouldn't work tho.