# Ajax not work in android device browser

Tags: php, android, ajax

I am using ajax function for checking username and password but some android device does not support it. so what i have to do? This is my ajax function

```
$(function()
  {
    $("#loginform").submit(function()
    {
      document.getElementById('loading').style.display = "block";
      var formData = new FormData($("#loginform")[0]);
      $.ajax({
        url: 'login_check.php',
        type:'POST',
        data: formData,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        cache: false,
        mimeType: 'multipart/form-data',
        success: function(html)
        {       

        }                   
    });
    return false
    });
  });
```

Comment: I think all android browsers support ajax: http://quirksmode.org/m/table.html#t12

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11434930/jquery-ajax-fails-on-android-tablet-browser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably your issue relates not to ajax not being available, but to a bad browser response. See [this](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=14924).